# Qt Creator Search inside code searches whole words only

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

Sometime ago, I remember I made `advanced search` and checked the ***Whole words only*** checkbox found beneath search box .. finished the search and unchecked the search filter.

Before that, I was always able to `search` inside code by *highlighting arbitrary text and doing simple search* (not advanced search) .. and the search always worked.
But now .. this simple search does not work .. the search only works when I highlight a Whole word, even though I am not doing advanced search nor any of the advanced search filter is checked ..
I want to know how to remove search filter for simple, inside code, search ...

Comment: `this simple search does not work`. Do you mean the search result is not `whole words only`?

Comment: @Aoyama , no, search should be possible even with any highlighted text .. which may, or may not be a _whole word_

Comment: The search just doesn't happen? This is so weird!

Answer (score 1):

Well, strange did not to think about it!
The simple search also has a filter list .. I just never noticed!
There is a search icon and a filter drop down inside the simple search box .. !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Whole word" is not working as I expect. Searching for `"XYZ"` (Whole word) matches `"XYZ_ABC"`, which is not a "Whole word" match.

Yeah yeah I know... switch from Qt 5 to Qt 6. Well that's not an option right now.